# Take data from user and use that data in a python script

Tags: php, python, html, user-input

I am a newbie in coding. I am learning php and python.

I want to take data from user. For this I used google and found a form based on html and php

index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="get">
TEXT1: <input type="text" name="text1">
TEXT2: <input type="text" name="text2">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now data.php can use:

$_GET["text1"]
$_GET["text2"]

But my script is in python. I don't know how to use the data given by user.

Please help.

Regards,
Abhishek.

Comment: Save it to a file or database using PHP then load it using Python.

Comment: Will definitely try it but I fear that if many people access it at a time it can create a problem. Maybe I am wrong but just doubt that if someone gets result with wrong data... I mean he entered something and get result for something else...

Sorry for silly question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* the system(..) [http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php] command to call your python script with command line arguments.

```
system('python myScript.py ' . $_GET['text1'] . ' ' . $_GET['text2']);
```

Although I would really advice **against** using user provided input in this way, if a user would send `1;rm -rf /;echo` as $_GET['text1'] your system would die.. (assuming apache is running as root, which would also be a bad idea)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am not having root access... Will this still work?

Ans can you tell some way to prevent hackers from killing the m/c? Else no one will use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a python framework like Pylons/Pyramid, you add your request parameters to your processing function, for instance:

`def process_data(request):`

```
   text1 = request.params.get('text1')
```